# Telerik reports subreports

Tags: c#, telerik, report, telerik-reporting

I'm starting with telerik reports so I have one question. In my report I need to create maser report for every chosen product and below it I need to show report for each selected product detailed. So when I chose some products in reports parameters listbox I see my summary report but don't know how to add as many detailed reports below it as user has chosen in listbox. Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telerik supports subreports like you need.  Here are the basic steps:

1. Build a new report to display the detail information.  It should have a parameter that is the 'current' product (it sounds like you might already have this report)
2. On your main product report (the master), place a `SubReport` control in the detail section.  Set the `Report` property of the `SubReport` to the report you created above.
3. Set the `Parameters` property on the `SubReport` to pass the product from the current detail row to the subreport.

For more information, you can reference Telerik's [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/report-items-sub-report.html), a [live demo](http://demos.telerik.com/reporting/Examples/ProductCatalog/DefaultCS.aspx), or the [API reference](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/allmembers_t_telerik_reporting_subreport.html).